# pgfplots: enlarge x limits abs value and date coordiantes

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

Enlarging x limits of date coordinates by an absolute value used to work with pgfplots 1.4, but it gives me an error with the newer version 1.8. Can anyone suggest a working solution to the minimal example below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel style=
{rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
xticklabel=\day. \hour:\minute,
date ZERO=2009-08-18,% <- improves precision!
enlarge x limits={abs=2009-08-18 06:00},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(2009-08-18 09:00, 050)
(2009-08-18 12:00, 100)
(2009-08-18 15:00, 100)
(2009-08-18 18:35, 100)
(2009-08-18 21:30, 040)
(2009-08-19,       020)
(2009-08-19 3:00,  000)
(2009-08-19 6:0,   035)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the error? Btw, `Pgfplots 1.5.1` works fine.

Comment: In this particular example it complains about 08 being out of range octal number, but changing 2009-08-18 to 2009-07-18 gives an error about ill-formated floating point number.